# Get the list of all the models, that current user connected to

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates

I hope, that I wrote the Title correctly...)))

I have the model `article`, that can connect to User through `ManyToMany` field.

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db import models

class Article(models.Model):
    class Meta():
        db_table = 'article'

    article_users = models.ManyToManyField(User, null=True, blank=True, default=None)
    article_title = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=False, null=False)
    article_content = models.IntegerField(choices=CONTENT_CHOICES, null=True, blank=True)
```

And I can list all the users, who connected to that model in the template through:

```
{% for user in article.article_users.all %}
    {{ user.username }}
{% endfor %}
```

But how can I list all the models, to which is current User connected to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is that what you are looking for ?

```
{% for article in user.article_set.all() %}
    {{article.article_title}}
{% endfor %}
```

Maybe you will need to prevent this code if user is anonymous :

```
{% if user.is_authenticated() %}
    {% for article in user.article_set.all() %}
        {{article.article_title}}
    {% endfor %}
{% else %}
    # Do something for anonymous users.
{% endif %}
```

**Edit** : replaced request.user with user

Comment: Yes, that was actually what I need. And again I forgot about `_set`...:/ Thanks a lot. P.S.: no `request` method needed as far as I try. Just `user.article_set.all`. Request and brackets are need in views...

Comment: @spirit : yes indeed, request isn't needed in template tags. If my answer is what you're looking for, please click the green check to set it as accepted.

Answer (score 1):

Can't you write something like this in your view :

```
Article.objects.filter(article_users=current_user)
```

or should the request necessarily be in the template ?

(see also [the django documentation for Many to many relationship](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/))